# How change x.0 to x?

Tags: java

in 120/10 result is 12.0
I want res to be 12 in float mode
can I change 12.0 to 12?

```
Float x =120f;
Float y =10f;
res.setText(x/y);
```

finally res> 12.0

Comment: Don't declare `x` and `y` as objects, declare them as primitive type. So use `float`, not `Float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.format()`

```
String.format("%.1f", 12.0f); //returns "12,0"
String.format("%.0f", 12.0f); //returns "12"
String.format("%.1f", 120f / 10f); //returns "12,0"
String.format("%.0f", 120f / 10f); //returns "12"
```

also check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) link for further information, or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to int.

```
res.setText((int)(x/y));
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @ronmrdechai's answer, only if you want to round the result, which will be something like

```
int result = (int)(x/y + 0.5f);
res.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Float x =120f;
Float y =10f;
res.setText((int)(x/y));
```

You have to cast it to an `int`. That, or make their types `ints`/`Integers` originally.